# Stylish progress indicator for iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, progress-bar

In my application, I have multiple web service calls. To make my application more user friendly, I need stylish progress indicator for every operation(Deletion,updation,etc.). I have found the effective [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD). But i need my progress indicator more stylish than MBProgressHUD. Can anyone provide the solution to make my application with stylish progress indicator.

Comment: This is really a UX/UI question - ask a designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look  out that some different

http://www.binpress.com/app/customizable-activity-indicator-for-ios/936

here you can get the multiple progress

http://code4app.net/category/hud

in native

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIActivityIndicatorView.html

Comment: i think http://code4app.net/category/hud this link gives the multiple choices

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look

https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLRemoteImageView

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2010/02/implementing-wait.html

http://www.raywenderlich.com/35720/paintcode-tutorial-custom-progress-bar

http://maniacdev.com/2013/08/open-source-ios-component-providing-an-ios-7-style-progress-indicator

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/alroundprogressview

**Instead of SO, Google will provide you more options.**